# A question on Regular Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X$ & $Y$ be random vectors. Let $Z$=$f(X,Y)$ be a random variable.

Then if $X$ & $Y$ are independent, the following is a well known result:

$P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B)$

I need some help to 'formalize' what appears to be an intuitive generalization when $X$ & $Y$ are not assumed to be independent, namely that

$P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$

without assuming $Y$ is discrete.

One 'immediate' problem for example is that, I am not sure that the RHS of the above equation is well defined.

For in *Breiman's text 'Probability'*, by *Definition 4.7*,  the conditional probability $P(C\mid Y=y)$ is defined as a measurable function in $y$ satisfying

$P(C, Y\in A )$=$\int_{A} P( C\mid Y=y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$ where $C$ is a measurable subset of the sample space and $A$ is an arbitrary Borel subset in the state space of $Y$.

Notice that $C$ is held fixed in the definition, as $y$ is allowed to vary.

Identifying $C$ with$[f(X,Y)\in B]$ in the LHS of our *conjecture*, allows us to make sense of $P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$.

But the subset $[f(X,y)\in B]$ changes with changes in $y$, hence at least by the above definition $P(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$ is not well defined. As an aside, for similar reasons, $E(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$ is also problematic.

Using the concept of Regular Conditional Probability, I think the statement above can be formalized as follows.

Let $X$ & $Y$ be random vectors. Let $Z$=$f(X,Y)$ be a random variable, and $P_{Y}$ be the marginal distribution of $Y$. Let $Q_{X\mid Y}(\cdot\mid y)$ be a regular conditional distribution for $X$ given $Y=y$.

Then $P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$, is I believe an ***intuitive interpretation*** of the following 'unproven' statement

$Q_{Z\mid Y}( B\mid y)$= $Q_{X\mid Y}(B_y \mid y)$

where $B$ is any arbitrary Borel subset of $R$, and  $B_y$ = $[x \mid f(x,y) \in B]$

and $Q_{Z\mid Y}(\cdot\mid y)$ the regular conditional distribution for $Z=f(X,Y)$ given $Y=y$.

Written alternatively we need to prove that

$P(Z\in B, Y\in A )$=$\int_{A} Q_{Z\mid Y}( B\mid y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$=$\int_{A} Q_{X\mid Y}( B_y\mid y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$

A related problem is to prove the following:

Let $P_{(X,Y)}$ be the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, $Q_{X\mid Y}(\cdot\mid y)$ be a regular conditional distribution for $X$ given $Y=y$, $P_{Y}$ be the marginal distribution of $Y$, and
let $D$ be a given Borel subset in the state space of $(X,Y)$.

Then
$P_{(X,Y)}(D )$=$\int Q_{X\mid Y}( D_y\mid y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$ where

$D_y$ = $[x \mid (x,y) \in D]$

Comment: Thanks for the edit Davide

Comment: @Davide Reaching out to you, as you were helpful in editing my question. Just wondering if the question that the seemingly 'intuitive' statement  $P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$ might be wrong is not interesting or that I have not framed the issues well, as I obviously have got no reply. As an aside the above statement does not appear at all in some standard texts like Brieman's or Wiliam's etc possibly suggesting that it is not true.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97422/probability-distribution-of-functions-of-random-variables).